# A power of 0.8 implies a main effect of 2.8

Tags: statistical-power

Can anybody please explicate [the following statement](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need-16-times-sample-size-estimate-interaction-estimate-main-effect/) by Andrew Gelman?

> If you have 80% power, then the underlying effect size for the main effect is 2.8 standard errors from zero. That is, the z-score has a mean of 2.8 and standard deviation of 1, and there’s an 80% chance that the z-score exceeds 1.96 (in R, pnorm(2.8, 1.96, 1) = 0.8).

Comment: What exactly do you find unclear about it?

Comment: Please see my answer below. I think I got confused by the code given. It is a nice trick if one wants to avoid typing `lower.tail = FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two-tail hypothesis with a significance level of 0.05 are assumed. The right-tail critical value is 1.96. The power is the mass of the sampling distribution under the alternative to the right of this decision boundary. Then we want to find a Gaussian with a standard deviation of 1 so that 80% of its mass is to the right of 1.96. Then a mean of 2.8 gives the desired outcome.

In R, it could be verified by `pnorm(1.96, 2.8, 1, lower.tail = FALSE)`, which is a more direct and verbose translation of the reasoning compared to the original code.

Comment: Ivan, @Tim - Given that we are thinking of a two-tailed test, doesn't the code need to be something like `pnorm(1.96, 2.8, 1, lower.tail = FALSE) + pnorm(-1.96, 2.8, 1, lower.tail = TRUE)`? Granted, one expression or the other is likely to be negligible...or am I not thinking about this in the right way?

Comment: The statement was about the right tail, and hence the calculation is limited to that tail.